# How to add a specularity map in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

I've seen some examples like on BlenderGuru.com and some other youtube tutorials. But, what would be considered the proper way to add a specularity map in cycles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it just like blender guru. To do this see image:

[image]

To be more specific, Cycles is a unbiased ray tracing engine. That means that computer actually computes the rays of light in the scene. Because of this the specularity of a material is not controlled by a setting, but by the actual physical properties that create the effect. For this reason their is **no specularity setting**.

The reason why some render engines have a control for specularity is because they fake the effect.

Answer (score 5):

I would use a mix node and connect the map to the *factor* input:

[image]

Also see these related questions:

- [I'd like to have portions of a texture not glossy](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5069/599)
- [How does fac differ with manual control versus node control?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/10595/599)