# Smooth transition between glossy and color material

Tags: materials, color

I would like to make the white part of the tooth(bottom) below to be glossy and the other color to be simple with no reflection. I still have to keep the reflection at the same location of the object, while getting rid of the darker sides. I'm using the cycles render and a Hemi light.
[image]

Below are the material nodes used for the material, which I followed from another thread.
[image]

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13600/how-to-add-a-specularity-map-in-cycles and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13600/how-to-add-a-specularity-map-in-cycles

Comment: You want to get rid of the darker parts left and right of the white tooth base?

Comment: Right now your nodes *do* give you the glossy bottom, and top to be a simple diffuse material with no reflections. So can you edit and clarify your question?

Comment: Yes, the main concern is getting rid of the dark lateral parts and that small reflection where the color is changing.  I tried moving the light or different light, but still didn't manage to get the desired result. PS, I'm kinda new to Blender, sorry if I asked anything stupid.

Comment: Have you tried placing more lights all around it to lit up the dark areas? If you want the white part to be glossy, it will have reflections!