# Two Different materials in One Object

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

In the İmages you can see the vase has a 2 different colours. The top is white and opaque, and the bottom is transparent and dark blue (thanks to my webcam you'll see it as black). My question is how can I colour my model vase like the real one?

[image]

[image]

Comment: For cycles: and  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50360/smooth-transition-between-glossy-and-color-material

Comment: @tahs.  Please note the difference between renderers.  Blender Render vs Cycles Render.  In the images above you are using Blender Render.

Answer (score 1):

**Blender Render Material, Texture, UV**

Not Cycles

[image]

- UV Map Vase in Edit Mode .. Project from View Bounds
- Material Panel.  Transparency On. Alpha Zero.
- Texture Panel using UV,  Color Ramp with Colors and Alpha indicated
- Texture Panel Influence Affect Color 1.0 and Alpha 1.0 as depicted
- Texture Settings shown in 2 Panels to Save Vertical Space
- No emphasis on Artistry. You Can do better.  Suit to your taste.

[image]

- Emphasis on UV Map.  Pay no attention to the man ... rather the image behind the Vase.
- Same Material and Texture Panels

Comment: How can I change interface like you did ?