# Maps in Cycles Render

Tags: normals

Sorry if this question has already been asked, but I just started using Cycles after using internal for a while now and it's kind of confusing. So I was wondering how I can apply normal maps. But for me it's not just normal maps. Usually in internal when I'd download a model it'd come with a normal map, occlusion map, specular map, and displacement map, and since i have no idea how to apply these I'd just go to the textures box, import all those maps, and under influence uncheck color and check normal. But in Cycles everything is different. How would I apply multiple maps as normals to a model in Cycles? Thanks so much!

Comment: [Bump maps with normal maps](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16443/using-a-normal-map-together-with-a-bump-map), specular, gloss and others - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27475/how-do-you-apply-a-gloss-and-spec-map-on-one-cycles-material, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13600/how-to-add-a-specularity-map-in-cycles

Comment: [How are texture maps imported into Blender?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18162/2217)