# Why does my model become partially transparent when using the alpha channel to control transparency?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor, transparency

Здравствуйте  не могу разобраться с прозрачностью
есть волк и текстуры.
почему то все становится полупрозрачным

Hi I can not understand with transparency
is a wolf and texture.
why everything becomes translucent
Download Blender File For Mega

https://mega.co.nz/#!EJ5miDrR!PFgflDbXDROdb0nBfxKqcdT79v0ucEcYGgKugwDYRLU

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is because the alpha channel is not completely opaque on the other parts:

[image]

The mix shader uses the top slot where the *Factor* input is 0, and the bottom slot where the *Factor* is 1. When the *Factor* is between 0 and 1, it will mix the two accordingly. See [How does fac differ with manual control versus node control?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/10595/599)

A quick fix you could do in this case is use a *Math* node with the operation set to *Greater than* to make the factor only have an input of 0 or 1, never a value in between:

[image]